# Drupal7 - In Edit View adding a field, no "Configure: field" popup and field not shown in "Fields" section

Tags: views

In View panel, adding fields not showing up "Configure: field" and the field is not added. i.e. The red-boxed is not shown as below (see step2):

Normal behavior step1:
[image]

Normal behavior step2:
[image]

The event happened after my

1. SuSE linux server upgraded from 11 to 12
2. PHP version upgraded from 5.3.17 to 5.5.14
3. Apache upgraded from 2.2.12 to 2.4.23

No application nor server-level's error log shown. Any ideas on how can I debug or trace the problem? Many thanks for yours help.

Comment: Have you tried flushing all sorts of cache, on all levels? Server, Drupal, browser? If you turn off javascript in your browser does it work, can you see the settings (it will reload the page and you'll probably have to scroll)? If the field is there but settings aren't showing up it's probably something with js.

Comment: The field still not show after turn off browser javascript. Any idea?